# How to scan and print to txt files when built jar file from netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

When I clean and build my program from `netbeans` it creates a .`jar` file. However this won't scan any `txt` files that are built inside of the jar file (was placed in the src file when building). However if the txt file is in the same folder as the .jar file it will then successfully scan and read from the txt file.

This would be fine apart from the fact that I want to have it as one file so that I can eventually turn it into an application that friends who don't have java on their computers can use.

How can I get the scanner to load the file into the program and then later use a `PrintWriter` to write to the same file?

I'm using something like this to scan it in.

> scanf=new Scanner(new File("Name.txt"));

Thanks in advance.

Its different because I need to use Scanners and PrinterWriters otherwise I have to go through and edit alot of code. Also none of the other questions address actually writing to file only reading it.

Comment: `"that friends who don't have java on their computers can use"` Why would anyone want to be friends with such people?

Comment: It's not different, it's the same. If you want a Scanner then [wrap the `InputStream` in one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream)). You cannot write to a file inside a Jar.

Comment: Then how would you save changes made to the file used if they need to be edited inside the program